# How to insert multiple selected data in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to select multiple data in database and also insert multiple data.
here is my query

Multiple Select:

```
<select name="sec_id[]" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker form-control border-input"
 style="text-align-last:center;" title="Select Section" required multiple>
<?php
$stmtSection = $crud->runQuery('SELECT * FROM tbl_section ORDER BY sec_id DESC');
$stmtSection->execute();
while($rowSection=$stmtSection->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  print("<option value='".$rowSection['sec_id']."'>".$rowSection['section']."</option>");
}
?>
</select>
```

Multiple Select to database:

```
  $sec_id = implode(', ', $_POST['sec_id']);

  $stmtSec = $crud->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_section WHERE sec_id IN (':sec_id')");
  $stmtSec->execute(array(":sec_id" => $sec_id));
  while($rowSec = $stmtSec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
     $section[] = $rowSec['section'];
  }
```

Multiple data insert to database: (Where I get error)

```
$query="INSERT INTO tbl_login(username,password,access_type,section,sec_id) 
        VALUES(:username, :password, :access_type, :section, :sec_id)";
if($crud->addAccount($account,$new_password,$access,$query,$section,$sec_id))
```

Function:

```
    public function addAccount($account,$new_password,$access,$query,$section,$sec_id)
    {
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$account,
                           ":password"=>$new_password,
                           ":access_type"=>$access,
                           ":section"=>$section,
                           ":sec_id"=>$sec_id));

      return $stmt;
    }
```

I am having problem with insert. 
please help me check my query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which problem do you have? If there are multiple rows to be inserted, it should be simple to run multiple `execute` calls

Comment: Undefined variable: section in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\Files-Server\Main\add-moderator-account.php

Comment: @NicoHaase heres the error

Comment: Well, then its obvious what to do: there should even be a line number in your error message telling you that the variable `$section` was not defined anywhere, but accessed